# What were those octopus creatures?

Tags: dc, character-identification, dc-extended-universe, suicide-squad

While going through Jotunheim, King Shark encounters some alien-looking octopus-esque creatures. They mimic his body shape as he moves around and later

> attack him with hidden razor teeth.

What's their deal? Are they from the comics? Are they connected to

> Starro?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

James Gunn [clarified on Twitter](https://twitter.com/JamesGunn/status/1375871872475127813) that they're called [Clyrax](https://dcextendeduniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Clyrax).

[image]

[image]

He revealed a bit more in a subsequent interview with Entertainment Tonight.

> ENTERTAINMENT TONIGHT: Um, question: those little, cute murder sea daddies... what do we call them? I love them.
>
> JAMES GUNN: Cute murd- oh, the Clyrax! King Shark's friends. Those are some sort of alien life that obviously they've picked up somewhere, that they've been keeping them alive in their aquarium.